# How to implement stripe idempotency key

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I have an array of customers for which I want to bulk charge them in stripe. Sometimes due to network, some charges don't go through while some do therefore making a new request charges all customers again. I read that I could use idempotency but noticed the key regenerates each time I make a request. How do I implement generating the key to identify each user without storing the key in the DB since it is meant to be a temporary key?

```
 for(customer in customers){
     stripe.charges.create({
        amount: 2000,
        currency: "usd",
        source: token,
        customer: stripe_customerId,
    }, {
       idempotency_key: uuid
    }, function(err, charge) {
        // asynchronously called
    });
}
```

Any ideas on this, please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, you probably don't want to do a `for` loop for asynchronous code like this; if you have `n` Customers to charge, you'll make `n` simultaneous requests, and that could cause a whole range of problems.

Second, you're using Charge code meant to create a one-off Charge from a Stripe Token, not [create a Charge from a Customer](https://stripe.com/docs/saving-cards).

Assuming you actually have saved Customer IDs, you'll probably want to look at using something like [async](https://caolan.github.io/async/) for this.

I would approach it using [`#queue`](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#queue), and I'd split things up as follows:

1. Iterate over the Customers, and for each, create a 'task' that includes the `customer` ID, the `amount`, the `currency`, a newly-generated `idempotency_key`, and an `attempt_count`, and then push that task onto the queue;
2. in the Queue 'processing' function, I would try creating a Charge with that task and its data, and if it fails due to a networking or other retryable error, I would increment `attempt_count` and push it back onto the queue so it can be retried.  I'd probably also have a test to limit the number of retries, and skip/log any that failed, i.e. 5 times.

Comment: I have a related question. What if I just use some "async loop" of retries in context of Stripe events handler, and if I generate some id, and try action with this action id, without saving that id, but just using same id for same context & "async loop" of retries? Is this enough? Saving operation metadata for literally any change made via Stripe API would be an overkill in my context, because I already can review API calls history for a customer or payment_intent at Stripe UI page for developers.